# How can I add the Edit/View/Share icon to a list item? SharePoint 2013

Tags: list, list-view, configuration

How do I add this ellipsis icon so the item can be edited more easily?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Where do you want to show the icon? In a view?

Comment: In the same place would be fine, right after Title?

Comment: See Dylan Cristy 's answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that by editing the view.

If you modify the view, you will see several options for the Title field:

- Title
- Title (linked to item)
- Title (linked to item with edit menu)

Choose the option that includes the edit menu in your view.

Comment: Works great! Thanks once again, Dylan- I'd always wondered what that other option for Title meant. So that field can be renamed and that ellipsis icon would go anywhere in the list order then right?

Comment: Yes, it can be renamed, and you can move it around in the view by specifying the "position from left" when you edit the view.  If you need to move that field around in the forms (new/edit/display), I believe you'd need to enable content types for the list and then edit the "Item" content type to specify the order of the fields in the content type definition.